# Change icons in Nemo bookmarks bar

Tags: nemo

http://gyazo.com/035b3091cf7b47247f10a78fa48a9c88

I want to change Video and Games icon on that side bar

I looked up the icons I want and found them in the directory /usr/share/icons/Numix/16x16/places

Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 Lenovo Y580

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Edited:  If you are in your Homes folder when you have Nemo open, in the right screen, select the folder you want to change. Right-click it and select Properties. Then click on the icon of the folder in the upper left of the Properties that just came up. It will allow you to select the custom icon you want.

Comment: I need to be able to change the icons on the side bar, not in my file system.

Comment: Mine changed there when I tested that.

Comment: They're custom shortcuts, not the original ones.

Comment: Are you running Nemo as root user or as a regular user?  I could not change the icons as root user, it would not take it.  Plus, if the folder was owned by root without permissions for everybody else, I couldn't change it.  Only as a regular user I could change it.  Any changes I made to the folders in the right workspace, it would automatically update the folder on the left pane.

Comment: That was even with a custom shortcut by dragging a games folder to the left pane.

Comment: When I right click it on my left side bar I don't get properties.

Comment: You can't right-click it on the left side bar.  It is duplicating what is in the workspace to the right.  You only need to right click the folder in the right workspace that matches what is on the left.  Every change I have made has instantly updated to the pane on the left.

Comment: work for me under xenial, I use /usr/icons/Humanity/ then emblems or places and 32 size is ok

Comment: Does not work in Nemo 3.8.6—it changes the icon in the main Nemo window, but not in the bookmarks bar ('left pane') (which, BTW, _can_ be right-clicked, but the context menu only has options for Open/Remove/Rename).